# Convert image into 4x4 non-overlapping blocks

Tags: python, image-processing

I want to divide an image into 4x4 non-overlapping blocks in python and then convert that block into array of 16 element.

Comment: Great! What have you tried? What did you expect? What happened instead? Without a [mcve] we can't do much to help.

Comment: I used Image.open() to read the image then convert it into ndarray with numpy.asarray, then I tried to split the array but I don't think it's working properly.

Comment: Why don't you show your code? Also: it might be a good idea to use some external special library (not necessarily because your problem is hard; but it will be optimized, robust and maybe there is other stuff you want to do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using a quality-library like [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/), especially if there are more steps needed in the future. It is based on numpy/scipy.

A kind of minimal example ([from the docs](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/numpy_operations/plot_view_as_blocks.html?highlight=block)) would be the following.

#### Code:

```
from skimage import data
from skimage import color
from skimage.util import view_as_blocks

# get astronaut from skimage.data in grayscale
l = color.rgb2gray(data.astronaut())

# size of blocks
block_shape = (4, 4)

# see astronaut as a matrix of blocks (of shape block_shape)
view = view_as_blocks(l, block_shape)

# collapse the last two dimensions in one
flatten_view = view.reshape(view.shape[0], view.shape[1], -1)

print(flatten_view.shape)
```

#### Output

```
(128, 128, 16)  # 128x128 blocks a 16 elements each
```